# Excel in SharePoint - Refresh button directs to "Save As" which doesn't save changes

Tags: excel, save

I use several Excel spreadsheets stored on our company's internal SharePoint site. When I open these in Excel ("Edit in Excel", not the Excel web app), then click the Refresh button at the top, it no longer refreshes as normal. What happens is that the Save As menu appears. If I save as a new file with a new name, it saves correctly. My other choice is to overwrite the existing file, but this doesn't work. After the overwrite, if I click on the file name at the top of Excel and click Version history, it does say I just saved the file. If I exit, then on the SharePoint page, the "Modified" column also correctly updates. But when I reopen the file, the changes I made and thought I saved don't appear.

Any ideas?

This problem started two days ago. My work has Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus and my Excel is Version 1805 (Build 9330.2087). My computer is running Windows 10 Pro, Version 1703, OS Build 15063.1088.

Comment: So you are trying to save on the share point site?

Comment: Yes, trying to save on SharePoint site through the refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are aware of this the changes will be saved automatically

[image: Changes are saved automatically]

Comment: Let me clarify. It's an Excel sheet stored on the SharePoint site. But I make my edits by clicking on the file to open in the Web App, then EDIT WORKBOOK>Edit in Excel. In that window, there is a save/refresh button, with the image you have above.

Answer (score 0):

At first my IT staff said to check for Office updates (none detected), then restarting the programs, and trying a different browser than Chrome. None of these worked.

The solution? A good old-fashioned restart.